# WYSIWYG editor not executing the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, content-editor

I'm trying to build a simple text editor with the help of `document.execCommand`, I'm stuck with the condition statement on this:

```
$('[data-nitsedittag]').click(function (e) {
 var selection = window.getSelection();
 var $parent = $(selection.anchorNode.parentElement);
 if ($parent.data('nitsselect') == uniquid && $parent.is(':focus')) {
     var tag = $(this).data('nitsedittag');
      switch (tag) {
      default: document.execCommand(tag);
      }
}
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've included the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v09xg7f3/)

Right now I'm executing only bold and italics just for testing purpose. Please help me out.